# Calling an array operator

Tags: java, arrays, class

Good evening everyone. I'm working my way through this and have hit a block in regards to using a class inside another class. Eclipse informs me that the error is a result of trying to call a static reference to a non-static method. 
 All I am trying to do is use the method "reverse" multiple times in one program. I know that the issue is in the "reverse" class, and am looking to find the correct way format the class to accept input from the code in the main method.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
      //creating a test array
      int [] myArray = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7 ,8 ,9};
      int [] myArrRev = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
      reverse (myArray);
      if ( Arrays.equals(myArray, myArrRev))
         System.out.println("reverse worked for 10 elements.");


      int [] myArray2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7 ,8};
      int [] myArrRev2 = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
      reverse (myArray2);
      if ( Arrays.equals(myArray2, myArrRev2))
         System.out.println("reverse worked for 9 elements.");


      int [] myArray3 = {0};
      int [] myArrRev3 = {0};
      reverse (myArray3);
      if ( Arrays.equals(myArray3, myArrRev3))
         System.out.println("reverse worked for 1 element.");

      int [] myArray4 = {};
      int [] myArrRev4 = {};
      reverse (myArray4);
      if ( Arrays.equals(myArray4, myArrRev4))
         System.out.println("reverse worked for 0 elements.");
   }




   void reverse( int arr[] ){
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++)
         {
         int temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
         arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
         }
   }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the method declaration to:

```
   static void reverse( int arr[] )
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without making it static? i tried removing "static" from the main method, but that obviously wont work.

Comment: @JWelch What's the problem with making it `static`? But yeah, you can create an instance of your class, then use that instance to call the non-static method. But why? What's the point of that? The method is not using *any* fields of the class, so why?